# trying to install gloudemans/shoppingcart, Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content?

Tags: laravel, plugins, dependencies, composer-php

I tried to install gloudemans/shoppingcart facing an error:

```
Installation failed, reverting 
Problem 1
    - Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/events 5.1.*
```

I tried also to install different version of laravel and `illuminate/events` like required but still nothing, having always the same issue.

composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/events 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.17.2, required as ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.17.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

`composer require illuminate/events 5.1.*`:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.41
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.31
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.30
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.28
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.25
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.22
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.20
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.16
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.13
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/events v5.1.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.3
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.4
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.5
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.7
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.0.8
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.1.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.1.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.1.3
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.2
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.3
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.11.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.12.0
- Installation request for illuminate/events 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: I have faced the same problem few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your `composer.json` you didn't install `illuminate/events`. so can you install `illuminate/events` and after that install `gloudemans/shoppingcart`. It will work. when you install use `composer require illuminate/events` and then composer require `gloudemans/shoppingcart`

Comment: After correctly installed  illuminate/events the problem still persist

Comment: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.17.2`

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 5.7 or above, the shopping cart package does not work anymore. Here is a fork that works exactly the same way but supports newer versions of Laravel:

https://packagist.org/packages/hardevine/shoppingcart